# jQuery toggleClass not working with li?

Tags: jquery

I am just working on simple TODO app. And I am trying to create a toogleable strike effect on a text on click. Here is my code.

css

```
.striked{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("ul").on("click","li",()=>{
    $(this).toggleClass("striked");
});
```

Any line inside the function runs but toogleClass shows no effect. Please help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery's `this`, you need to use `function () {}`, not `() => {}`. Arrow functions capture the surrounding `this`, which is not what you want with jQuery.

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("striked");
});
```

Comment: ah such a stupid mistake I made

Comment: Happens to everyone. :)